# rfkill command doesn't list my bluetooth in Ubunt 18.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

[image: Settings screen]

I have a problem with my bluetooth adapter in my Lenovo Thinkpad T420. 
I'm adding the screenshot of my settings. 
The result of `rfkill list` is :

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The result of `lsusb` :

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:301b Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b221 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd integrated camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And the result of `lspci` is

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
0d:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 08)
0d:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 04)
```

I'm not sure of what's wrong in my PC.

And for the command :

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | awk '/301b/' RS=
```

The result is :

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=32 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=413c ProdID=301b Rev=11.19
S:  Manufacturer=Dell
S:  Product=Dell Universal Receiver
C:* #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   8 Ivl=10ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   8 Ivl=2ms
I:* If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  32 Ivl=2ms
```

Comment: Is it supposed to have bluetooth?

Comment: Yes. When I got this laptop it was on windows. And everything was working fine. I removed windows completely and installed Ubuntu 18.04 lts. After that I have this Bluetooth problem. I tried so many similar posts. But nothing worked for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | awk '/301b/' RS=`

Comment: I don't think your laptop is equipped with a bluetooth device